# java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror. where to add .so file in eclipse for android application

Tags: java, android, jar, java-native-interface

I have created `.so` file using android NDK. In xxx.java class I added some native methods to call from c/c++ files. these native methods I am calling in my own methods for example like below,

```
static
    {
    System.loadLibrary("print");
    }
    public native String print(String pM,int len);
    public native int openPrint();
```

The above native methods are calling in my method so that other android application developer can use as an API's.

```
public static void foo(){

         openPrint()
    }
```

Is this right way ?

For this reason I created one `myprint.Jar` file. it includes the `libprint.so` file also.

I added above jar file in another application, It's importing the class from xxx.java but whenever I tried to run the application its throwing an error saying that

```
  FATAL Exception,
  java.lang.UnsatisifiedLinkerror....
```

How to solve the above problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813336/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .so file should be place in libs-->armeabi-->xxx.so folder of eclipse. then create build.properties file in eclipse and mention the path of xxx.so file by doing like this

```
open build.properties file. 

   then click on Add Library button. 

   then one edit box will appear write below line in the edit box.



external.libs.dir=libs
```

Answer (score 1):

The `libprint.so` needs to be put in the libs folder, and then loaded using:

```
System.loadLibrary("print");
```

May be you have `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` because, the c function name didn’t match the fully qualified name of your java class.
i suggest to follow this link: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: Thanks for ur rply. I added System.loadLibrary in xxx.java. and created myprint.jar. Is it necessary to add in android application also where I am adding .jar file??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434529/how-to-load-a-native-shared-object-in-a-jar-from-an-android-application